# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n d\lambda(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$, then compute: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n d\lambda(x)$$

I thought of using the Monotone Convergence Theorem to pass the limit inside:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n d\lambda(x)=\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n d\lambda(x)=\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}e^{-2x}\,d\lambda(x)$$

Since the function $e^{-2x}$ is continuous then:
$$\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}e^{-2x}\,d\lambda(x)=\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}e^{-2x}dx=-\frac{e^{2x}}{2}|_0^{\frac{n}{2}}=?$$

**Questions:**

Now the $\frac{n}{2}$ gets unaffected by the limit if I apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem. What am I doing wrong? How should I compute the integral?

Comment: MCT or DCT requires that all the integrals live on the same measure space. But the integrals in OP live on different spaces for different $n$'s, so you cannot apply MCT directly. To put them on the same ground, we can rephrase the integral as $$\int_{0}^{\frac{n}{2}} \left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n\,\lambda(\mathrm{d}x)=\int_{[0,\infty)} \left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n\mathbf{1}[x\leq n/2]\,\lambda(\mathrm{d}x),$$ where $\mathbf{1}[\cdots]$ is the [indicator-function notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). Now you can apply MCT to the integrals on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you should apply MCT to is $f_n(x) = 1_{(0,n/2)}(1-2x/n)^n$ where $1$ is the indicator function. Note that in the MCT the underlying set of integration is the same throughout. Here you may apply MCT as you have done, realizing that $1_{(0,n/2)}\uparrow  1$ and $(1-2x/n)^n\uparrow e^{-2x}$.

Comment: There is an even more "economical" way to solve this issue by remarking that the integrand has a very simple primitive... see duplicate question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1291627

Answer (score 0):

Are we using a rocket launcher to take down a cockroach? Define
$$u=1-\frac{2x}{n}$$
Then the integral becomes
$$\int_0^1 x^n \frac{n}{2}dx=\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\rightarrow .5$$